# CSS Flex-box - Trim box containing long text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm playing with flexbox system in CSS and I can't figure out how to solve my problem.

If I have box with long text, which breaks to two lines, box grows to full width available and I don't want that. If text is on many lines then I want box to grow to width of the longest line. Well, my english is not so good that's why I have images to better show what I want to achieve.

This is what I have now:

[image: This is what I have now]

And this is what I want to have:

[image]

I looked for ready solution in google (and stackoverflow) but without luck.
I prepared also JSFiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/f98VN/4/

Is it possible to do what I want and if yes then how can I achieve that? If not, what are your suggestions?

Code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-parent">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <div class="item2">text is here</div>
    <div class="item1"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 550px; /* it has width of the whole page, in fiddle I changed it to fixed */
    align-items: center;
}

.item1 {
    background: red;
    height: 100px; /* it has constant width */
    width: 100px;
}

.item2 { /* it's width is fluid, depends on text inside which is modified by JS */
    background: pink;
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Tried 100% width on your first CSS style?

Comment: try to adjust flex value on childs  http://jsfiddle.net/f98VN/8/ and align-self. But this will need to be retune if text is different http://jsfiddle.net/f98VN/9/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may shrink middle container to the longest word using :`display:table;width:1%;` **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f98VN/11/)** or use `inline-block` and `inline-table`, dropping the flexmodel : **[DEMO *(this is it)*](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BiLHd)**

To keep words together you may use a non breaking character `&nbsp;` in between words you want to keep aside on same line : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f98VN/12/)**

Edit: 
Above demos works in some browsers. In Chrome and Opera content moves to the side of the page.
Fixed version: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/izKFG

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats the way I wanted it to be. :)

Comment: perfect, note that display:table will shrink/expand to it's content, setting a small width makes it to wrap inline content

Comment: hmm, I studied it a little deeper and it's not quite full solution. Because of that width: 1% the content is moved to the side, not center on page. You can clearly see this on Your fiddle example. I will try modify Your code to find fully solution.

Comment: I've had to uncheck acceptation of the answer. Solution is almost good, problem is that whole content moves from center of the page because of that width: 1%. `justify-content: center` "thinks" that middle box has 1% width and not its real width which is much more. :/ I played around with that code and it looks like it simply cannot  be done the way I want it.

Comment: @Rob okay, i'm not sure to understand, if i st border and margin auto to flex-parent, i see all 3 boxes in center. Do you have a link where your trouble shows up or is it with a peticular browser ? test here http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/eLycj

Comment: @Rob  ... hmm i saw a bug in opera, flex has still to mature a bit , try this fix : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/izKFG wich i dislike. i'll be off for next hours

Comment: That bug is in Chrome to, but your magic from fixed version solved this issue. IE still has problems but I think that it is acceptable because IE almost all the time has problems. ;) I need to read about @-moz-document url-prefix() because I didn't know that. Thanks a lot for Your time and help!

Comment: @Rob maybe the option is not to use the flexbox on this one : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BiLHd

Comment: Yes, that is good choice. I've never before used display: inline-table. Without it my issue wasn't possible to solve other way than with flexbox. With inline-table it is good and more supported way so I will do this that way. Again- thanks a lot for your time, I learned new things. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the extra space appears because the whitespace break is a fake effect applied by the browser. What in fact happens, and it's hidden by the browser, is that the word is breaking between its letters, then the extra-space is actually the space that the letters really take.

You can see it by setting the text div to `word-break: break-all;` http://jsfiddle.net/f98VN/10/

[image]

It's not the effect you asked, but at least it doesn't leave extra space.

Comment: I figured it out that it's the reason of my problem. The thing is that I can't have words broken on letters. @GCyrillus just solved my issue. Thanks for help!

Answer (score -1):

I got it to appear the way you want using percentages not fixed pixel width,

```
changed width: 550px; to width:70%;
```

check out this [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/f98VN/7/)

Comment: Makes it worse (at least on my screen)

Comment: Why would you set a fixed width in pixels for something that's flexible? You need to adjust the percentage to make it look better for you.

Comment: I've set fixed width on parent just for this fiddle example. In fact I have it on width 100% but it centers on page (also with flex). Text in pink is dynamically modified with JavaScript so one time it will have text: "one" which is for, lets say 50px width, and another time pink div have text "something long" and then it will have bigger width. Thats why I can't set constant width 70%, it must be flexible. @GCyrillus solved issue so You can check it out. Thanks for help. :)